# .net core get Oauth2 access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, .net-core

I have a working (tested) oauth response from postman, but unfortunately I don't know which way to go when I need to implement the query in .net Core.

Please can you give me a simple example or a hint?

Comment: What kind of token are you querying? Are you accessing the IEP server or the service provider? What kind of IDP product do you use? Do you want to know how to do HTTP requests? Or Oauth2 details. Too fuzzy to me

Answer (score -1):

The [Identity Server 4 Samples repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts), have a lot of examples of OAuth clients.

The steps you need to execute to authenticate, depends of the flow used by the server, more information about flows and usage http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/grants.html

Comment: Please do not provide links as answers. The above returns a 404.

Comment: Fixed the broken link.